# Number of inverses for each element of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra

A group is defined as a semigroup with unity, in which all elements have an inverse. Does every element have an unique inverse, or can this be not a case?

Comment: Let $g_{1}$ and $g_{2}$ be two inverses of a same element $g$. By definition, $e=g_{1}g=g_{2}g=gg_{1}=gg_{2}$. As the law of a group is associative, by (right)-multiplying by $g_{1}$, we get $g_{1}(gg_{1})=g_{2}(gg_{1})$, hence $g_{1}=g_{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An inverse for $x$ is an element $y$ such that $xy=1$ and $yx=1$ (where $1$ is the unity). Suppose also $z$ has the same property, that is, $xz=1$ and $zx=1$. Then
$$
z=z1=z(xy)=(zx)y=1y=y
$$

Note that associativity is crucial in the above proof for uniqueness of the inverse. Note also that this doesn't assume the semigroup is a group: *if* an element has an inverse, then the inverse is unique.

Comment: Can there be only one identity element in a semigroup, too?

Comment: @user285146 Yes: if $u$ and $v$ are identity elements, then $uv=u$ (because $v$ is identity) and also $uv=v$ (because $u$ is identity). Associativity is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

In a group the inverse is unique.
If $a\in G$ and $b,b'\in G$ are such that $ab=1=ab'$ then $a^{-1}ab=a^{-1}ab'\Rightarrow b=b'$.